# File extension validation with python

Tags: python, linux, file-extension, file-type

I want to check if a given file's extension is correct or not. For example, someone give me a file with an extension .zip but actually it may be an executable.

Using `mimetypes` I could not determine a file's real type. As far as I see, `mimetypes` needs an extension.

I can map the output of unix `file` command with some extensions. Even if you change the extension, you cannot deceive `file` command. However, this solution needs a subprocess.

I thought, there may be a more pythonic solution of this problem. Does anyone know?

Comment: @JesseJ It is no problem to me. It may be handled as text file. I want to seperate archive, executable, library etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the name of the C library (`libmagic`) used for the `file` command, nets [3 interesting python packages on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=libmagic&submit=search):

- [libmagic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libmagic/1.0) ([bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/xmonader/pymagic-dev))
- [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/0.4.3) (you can find some [documentation in the github repo](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic))
- [filemagic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/) ([github repo](https://github.com/aliles/filemagic))

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there is no absolute way of knowing.  For several reasons:

- Some file format use simple identifiers, but others don't.
- For those that don't, the only way is analyzing the behavior of a program able to able the format.  If the program can successfully open the file, then it belongs to it.
- But if not, the file could belong to hundreds of formats you don't have a program to open with.

I'm afraid you will need to be content with a partial answer like the ones you already have.